# My Blender animation was rendering and stopped suddenly by 14 frames?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

This is my First time rendering an animation in blender, and while my animation was rendering, it suddenly stopped at the 14th frame.

I don't know why, since I put the end frame at the place I wanted it to be, and I'm not sure where I would adjust thy frame rendering position.

If you're wanting any more addition information: I set my file formats/rendering images to be PNG, my render samples are 25, I set all of my images to a separate file. This is just information that I think would correlate to my problem, maybe.

Comment: Very casually you omitted any info about the scene. What is happening at that frame? Do you have any simulations going on (particles, fluid, cloth, smoke? Do you have motion blur? Please **[edit]** your question and add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem finally, and I guess I must of not had enough disk space on my computer to render out the other frames. If you ever render out your animation, maybe you just need to make some space on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

check the *start frame* and *end frame* in the render settings if they are set correctly.
also check the *frame step* if it's set to something other than 1.
You don't have to re-render from the beginning, just set the *start frame* to 15 to continue rendering from where you left off.